# New line inserted when passing a category link as a template parameter

Tags: mediawiki-templates

I have a mediawiki template which contains the following code: (there is more, but this is the part relevant to the question)

```
[[{{#if:{{{page|}}}|{{{page|}}}|{{{ns|}}}{{{1}}}}}]]
```

I tried to use it where `{{{ns}}}` is `:Category:`, but the first colon on `:Category:` creates an automatic newline (see https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Newlines_and_spaces#Automatic_newline).

How can I fix this template so it correctly creates the link without the automatic newline?

I tried adding `<nowiki/>` before `{{{ns|}}}`, but then I got a plain text link (`[[:Category:ParameterOne]]`) instead of a *linkified* link

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I didn't need to add the initial colon in `:Category:`, so I was able to solve this by simply adding the colon at the beginning of the link inside the Template.

I.e. I passed `Category:` (without a colon as a prefix) as the parameter `{{{ns}}}`, and changed the code to:

```
[[{{:#if:{{{page|}}}|{{{page|}}}|{{{ns|}}}{{{1}}}}}]]
```

Simply adding a colon before the `#if`.
Fortunately all other namespaces worked the same as before.